# GTK+ FT_Select_Size error

Tags: runtime, gtk

I have installed GTK+ 2.16 and Code::Blocks, trying to run a simple GTK+ program it gives me the following runtime error:

"The procedure entry point FT_Select_Size could not be located in the dynamic link library freetype6.dll"

I have checked the library exists, which it does, but I cannot seem to figure out how to fix this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem with Gtk+ 2.20, but i have no idea how to fix this, i'm using the All-in-one bundle from the Gtk+ website, but maybe there is some older version of freetype installed on my computer. Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using Windows.
The error you've seen has to do with missing Freetype library.

Simply download it from GTK+ Windows download page:
http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html

1. Go to the "Required third party dependencies" session.
2. Click on "Run-time" for Freetype to download.
3. Open the zip file, extract ./bin/freetype6.dll to %SystemRoot%\SYSTEM32 folder (i.e. C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 on English Windows)